# Adding loading state to map function causes items to display as loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map function displaying items:

```
 {data.map((item, index) => ())}
```

Within this function I would like to have an onClick that conditionally displays a loading state when loading is true.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

{data.map((item, index) => (
   <span
     onClick={() =>
     handleDelete()}>
  {loading ? (
    <LoadingSpinner />
       ) : (
    <TrashIcon />)} 
</span>
))}
```

When I do this it causes all items in the list to display the loading state, not just the item clicked on.

Is there a way I can achieve this using the index?

Comment: All of your child items are looking at the same loading state, you need to have a loading state for each item to control this individually. This would probably benefit from having a child component for the array items to do this.

Comment: Thanks @Jack, that makes sense. So I could have a child component such as <ItemCard />, then set the loading state on each one?

Comment: No problem, and yes - exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your map items are listening to a single boolean state value, instead, you can keep track of the index of the clicked item, or if you want to be able to click and show the loading state for multiple items you can use an array or Set.

Below is an approach using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set)

```js
const [loadingIndices, setLoadingIndices] = useState(new Set());
```

```js
{data.map((item, index) => (
   <span
     onClick={() =>
     handleDelete(index)}>
  {loadingIndices.has(index) ? (
    <LoadingSpinner />
       ) : (
    <TrashIcon />)} 
</span>
))}
```

Now in your handleDelete function, you can add index of the clicked element to the set in state.

```js
handleDelete = (selectedIndex) => {
  setLoadingIndices((prev) => new Set([...prev, selectedIndex]));
  // ...
  // ...
  // And to remove the element from loading state
  setLoadingIndices((prev) => {
    const updated = new Set(prev);
    updated.delete(selectedIndex);
    return updated;
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Abito, really great answer! I never knew about set, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your state in to the items instead of the parent. Updating state inside the parent component will cause all children to re-render.

```
const childComponent = (props) => { // you can pass the main loading state as a starting point
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(props.loading) // initial loader state
if(loading) return <LoadingSpinner />
return (
   <button onClick={()=> setLoading(prev => !prev)} /> 
)}
```

you can then mutate this to display different elements using if statements like above.

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean, I don't quit understand?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the re-render of children, You can use this index logic.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null);

const handleDelete = (index) => {
    setLoading(index);
}

{data.map((item, index) => (
   <span
     onClick={() =>
      handleDelete(index)}>
  {loading === index ? (
    <LoadingSpinner />
       ) : (
    <TrashIcon />)} 
</span>
))}
```